# How to delete a file without specifying its extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got files uploaded in a server, whose filenames are their id they have in my mongo database.

I've got a process that converts files from pdf to txt.

So, I want to delete the specified file without indicating it's extension.

Up to now, my code is as follows:

```
os.remove(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], str(document["_id"]) + ".txt"))
```

Comment: why don't you want to indicate the extension? because it isn't always `.txt` ??

Comment: Exactly, in order to manipulate the file, I need it to be a .txt, but the upload has to be a .pdf

Comment: so you want to delete both .txt and .pdf files? in the same folder?

Comment: the extension is nothing more than part of the name, it has to be there.

Comment: The question sounds like you want to delete some files but you don't know which ones :\

Comment: I want to delete files whose filename is known but not it's extension, which could be .txt or .pdf. It's like doing "if the extension of the file is .txt, delete filename.txt, else delete filename.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to search folders with wildcards.

```
doc = str(document[“_id”])
glob.glob(‘{}.*’.format(doc))
```

Comment: It run! Thank you so much